# Generate chart 3 using X,Y and Series

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have this json

```
    [{
    "serie": "Advertencia",
    "x": 4,
    "y": 15
}, {
    "serie": "Advertencia",
    "x": 6,
    "y": 18
}, {
    "serie": "Advertencia",
    "x": 5,
    "y": 19
}, {
    "serie": "Advertencia",
    "x": 10,
    "y": 23
}, {
    "serie": "Advertencia",
    "x": 12,
    "y": 25
}, {
    "serie": "Advertencia",
    "x": 7,
    "y": 25
}, {
    "serie": "Advertencia",
    "x": 9,
    "y": 25
}, {
    "serie": "Advertencia",
    "x": 3,
    "y": 26
}, {
    "serie": "Advertencia",
    "x": 8,
    "y": 27
}, {
    "serie": "Advertencia",
    "x": 1,
    "y": 29
}, {
    "serie": "Advertencia",
    "x": 11,
    "y": 32
}, {
    "serie": "Advertencia",
    "x": 2,
    "y": 33
}, {
    "serie": "Suspensao",
    "x": 5,
    "y": 1
}, {
    "serie": "Suspensao",
    "x": 2,
    "y": 2
}, {
    "serie": "Suspensao",
    "x": 8,
    "y": 3
}, {
    "serie": "Suspensao",
    "x": 4,
    "y": 3
}, {
    "serie": "Suspensao",
    "x": 7,
    "y": 4
}, {
    "serie": "Suspensao",
    "x": 9,
    "y": 4
}, {
    "serie": "Suspensao",
    "x": 3,
    "y": 4
}, {
    "serie": "Suspensao",
    "x": 1,
    "y": 5
}, {
    "serie": "Suspensao",
    "x": 10,
    "y": 5
}, {
    "serie": "Suspensao",
    "x": 11,
    "y": 5
}, {
    "serie": "Suspensao",
    "x": 12,
    "y": 6
}, {
    "serie": "Suspensao",
    "x": 6,
    "y": 6
}]
```

this json is generated from my query of database. One list with `X`, `Y` and `Series`
I want generate `c3 chart` with this json data, in this way.
I tried follow this documentation [c3 json data](http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-json), but the json data, is many different.

I did manually json data and this is expected result:
[image: chart]

Someone can generate c3 chart like above using format json cited here ?

**Edit1:** this is code that i can generate using c3, but i make do manually json data:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
      bindto: '#chart2',
      data: {
        type: 'line',
        labels: true,
        json: [
          {
            x:1, Suspensao: 10, Advertencia:3
          },
          {
            x:2, Suspensao: 3, Advertencia:5
          }
        ],
        keys: {
          x: 'x', // it's possible to specify 'x' when category axis
          value: ['Advertencia', 'Suspensao']
        }
      },
      axis: {          
      }
    });
```

**Edit2:** something like morris chart:

```
new Morris.Line({
  // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
  element: 'myfirstchart',
  // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
  // the chart.
  data: [
    { year: '2008', value: 20 },
    { year: '2009', value: 10 },
    { year: '2010', value: 5 },
    { year: '2011', value: 5 },
    { year: '2012', value: 20 }
  ],
  // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
  xkey: 'year',
  // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
  ykeys: ['value'],
  // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
  // chart.
  labels: ['Value']
});
```

Comment: If you have access to your SQL query, modify it to generate the proper output.

Comment: I have access to the sql query, the json / sql output I am using and the most elegant for something of that type, so I wanted to use it that way in C3.
Something like a morris chart json is ideal for that type. I put an example of the morris in question, it's a shame the morris have few graphics